# Rails 3 Nested Singular Resource new and edit router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my application a I have users and every user can have one banking_info. On the user page a have a link to banking_info, when I access the banking_info I would like to redirect to edit action on controller if there is an banking_info or redirect to new action if there isn't any banking_info. Which is the best way of doing that? Create a new method on bank_info controller to decide witch action the should redirect?

```
resources :users do
  resource :banking_info
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view:

```
<% if @user.banking_info.nil? %>
  <%= link_to "New banking info", user_banking_info_path(@user, @user.banking_info) %>  
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Edit banking info", new_user_banking_info_path(@user) %>  
<% end %>
```